# How to resolve the errors when Nugets need to be downgraded

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

My computer is using .NET 6, while another developer is using .NET 8.

I got his code and I am getting this error now

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
> 'C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\mudblazor\6.0.2\staticwebassets'

I googled to fix this issue and realized that these nuget packages are for .NET 8, while my computer is on .NET 6:

[image]

When I try to update, I get this error

> Error NU1202
> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization 8.0.3 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / browser-wasm. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization 8.0.3 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

How to resolve this issue with keeping my .NET 6 ?

Comment: _"My computer is using .NET 6, while another developer is using .NET 8."_ - you both need to be using the same version. There's no way around that. _"How to resolve this issue with keeping my .NET 6 ?"_ - **You can't**.

Comment: The only way to "solve" this would be to ensure that the *other developer* knows and understands this situation and agrees to use only Nuget packages that are supported by .NET 6. You need to talk together and agree on this - there's no technical trickery to "solve" this ...

Comment: The directory not found exception is not "normal". I feel like this question, trying to upgrade or not to target a different .NET version, is solving the wrong problem. Whatever is trying to access mudblazor directly is possibly doing the "wrong" thing. It should be using a PackageReference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a C# project targets a .NET version, it uses some features that are new to that version. Thus, all developers have to use that .NET SDK or newer.

You have 3 possible solutions:

### Downgrade the project to .NET 6

Replace the `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` tag in your `ProjectNameHere.csproj` file with `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

### Upgrade your setup to .NET 8

You can't update a single component to .NET 8 while the rest of your computer is running .NET 6.
[Download and install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80) .NET 8 from the linked Microsoft page.

### Target both .NET 6 and 8 side-by-side

C# supports targeting multiple .NET version simultaneously with the [TargetFrameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192074/targetframework-vs-targetframeworks-plural) tag.

You'd get 2 different version of your executable, one for each platform.

Note, however, that every time you use a .NET-8-only feature, you'd have to guard it with a precompiler condition:

```
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
  //... some .net8 specific code
#endif
```